# Angular what's the parent component for Material2 Dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use code like `const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(...);` in component `MyComponent`, which has provider `MyService`, and in the constructor of the  dialog, I have `public myService: MyService`, however, it comes the error `no provider for the service`, so what's the parent component that the dialog can succeed service from?

Comment: can you post a code example? Are you injecting `MyService` into the `DialogRef`? As long as the service is imported into the same (or higher) module as `MyComponent`, it should be injectable.

Comment: The error you get may be caused of your dialog not being inserted into the `entryComponents` array in your app module. Inside `@NgModule` properties, after all the  imports, providers, etc... check if you've added your dialog to the `entryComponents`. If not, add it. It would be something like `entryComponents: [MyDialogComponent]` in the end. But I kindly ask you to provide us some code, because as it is, your question seems a bit unclear to analyze...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of doing that.

1. As yer has told provide the service in module level. (app.module.ts or any other)
2. As marko has told pass it (code below)

   `const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AbcComponent, { myService: MyService });`

`export class AbcComponent {
        constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public myService: MyService, ...) {}
}`

Comment: I just find a new way, if the parent has the service, then use ViewContainerRef, and pass it to new MatDialogConfig(), which is passed to dialog.open()

Answer (score 0):

Material Dialog doesn't have a parent component. You can inject your service inside a component which calls `dialog.open` and pass it to the dialog configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the service in app.module.ts file.

```
import { MyService } from './myservice.service';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
     MyService
]
})
```